# React Apollo Updating Client cache.identify

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

**What I am trying to do:**

useMutation to edit the email value and re render the page. The data changes on refresh but the cache needs to change as well and I am having trouble modifying the cache.

**Legwork I have read/looked over before posting here:**

[Documentation on Mutations](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates)

[Documentation on Updating cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#example-updating-the-cache-after-a-mutation)

[Obtaining an Object's Custom ID](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#obtaining-an-objects-custom-id)

**What I think the problem is:**

the GraphQL database I am using does not implement a proper ID and I can not change that. I will have to modify the ROOT_QUERY cache and update it the hard way. As my code is right now It's reading the ID I want to use (email) as undefined. The error message simply reads as "Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot read property 'email' of undefined" pointing to functions in the node modules and nowhere near my function.

[My component's code can be found in full here](https://gist.github.com/BrianAKass/01c2928d35ac7a30e06b37b17394289f), but I will point to where I think the smoking gun ultimately is.

I have tried checking as much as I can but have no way of telling if i am reaching things correctly. I have looked at other stack posts, youtube, and tried reaching out to a few discord channels only to hit a wall. Any help and explanation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem was cache.identify was not needed at all! I just had to fix the InMemoryCahce at the index.tsx

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:8080/graphql",
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      People: {
        keyFields: ["email"],
      },
    },
  }),
});
```

This made things easier on getting the right index.